# PHP - How can I get rid of square bracket and index in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create string associated with an object and create an array. Instead of having 0 => array:1, 1 =>array:1, 2 =>array:1. I want to have just "orange" => Option {}, "mango" => Option{},   "banana" => Option {} in an array as Array:5

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "orange" => Option {#76 ▼
      -name: "american orange"
      -botanical: "citrus"
      -year: "1"
      -color: "orange"
      -size: "2"
      -scope: "season"
      -choices: []
    }
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "Mango" => Option {#3098 ▼
      -name: "american orange"
      -botanical: ""
      -year: "2"
      -color: "green"
      -size: "4"
      -scope: "season"
      -choices: []
    }
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "banana" => Option {#3099 ▼
      -name: "Billy"
      -botanical: ""
      -year: "1"
      -color: "dark"
      -size: "2"
      -scope: "season"
      -choices: array:5 [▼
        "" => ""
        "status" => "hard"
        "condition" => "ripe"
        "thickness" => "thick"
        "long" => "long"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

This is my code, **$options[] = [$resultKey => $option];** This is where i am getting it wrong.  **[$resultKey => $option]** is the one creating an array. All I want is $resultKey => $option so that I can achieve **"Orange" => Option{}**. I tried $options[] = (object)[$resultKey => $option]; it is still displaying indices. as I only want pair values without indices. ["Orange" => Option{},  "Mango" => Option{}, "Banana" => Option{} ]

````
 $options = [];

        foreach ($result as $resultKey => $resultValue) {
            $option = new Option($resultKey['scope'], $resultValue['name'], '', $resultValue['botanical'], $resultValue['year'], $resultValue['color'],  $resultValue['size'] !== 'choice' ? [] :$num[0]);
            $options[] = [$resultKey => $option];
           // dump([$resultKey => $option]);
        }
       ```
````

Comment: `$options[$resultKey] = $option;`

Comment: I did that also, but it only displays 1 element, instead of array. i..e Array:1["Orange" => Option{} ]

Comment: It's definitely not, and you're doing something wrong.

Comment: How? I have tried it and as you sent this, I have tried again.

Comment: $resultKey is a string, I tried to concatenate it with the object but it is complaining __Tostring()

Comment: Check this fiddle https://3v4l.org/7rqH3 and see how it differs from your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it as a blueprint. Gracias